# vector subscript out of range line 1475

Tags: c++

I can't figure out where the error is.

```cpp
vector<int> subVector(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) {
    vector<int> res;
    res = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < res.size() && i < b.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (res[i] < b[i]) 
        {
            int k = 1;
            while (res[i + k] == 0)
                k++;
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) 
            {
                res[i + j + 1]--;
                res[i + j] += 10;
            }
        }
        res[i] -= b[i];
    }
    return res;
}

vector<int> addVector(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) {
    vector<int> ans;
    ans.resize(max(a.size(), b.size()) + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        ans[i] = a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) 
    {
        ans[i] += b[i];
        ans[i + 1] += ans[i] / 10;
        ans[i] = ans[i] % 10;
        int k = i + 1;
        while (ans[k] >= 10) 
        {
            ans[k + 1] += ans[k] / 10;
            ans[k] %= 10;
            k++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

vector subscript out of range line 1475 and error debug.

I tried to fix it but couldn't. I can't understand how this error works.

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? You are accessing a vector using an index that is out of bounds. Use a debugger to step through the code until it performs behavior you are not expecting. Hint: your `while` loops are not checking to make sure `k` doesn't go out of bounds.

Comment: There are too many places to confirm whether the array is overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you are accessing a vector with the `[]` operator, and inside it, you are doing some arithmetic operation, you need to make sure that the result is not exceeding the vector boundaries.
For example:

```
vector<int> subVector(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) {
vector<int> res;
res = a;
for (int i = 0; i < res.size() && i < b.size(); i++) <--- 'i' is promised to be in 'res' boundry
{
    if (res[i] < b[i]) 
    {
        int k = 1;
        while (res[i + k] == 0) <--- 'i+1' can exceeds the 'res' boundry
        // Rest of the code ...
```

This is just one example. You are doing it all over your code.